# How can I overwrite the .on() Method in Famo.us

Tags: famo.us, surface

After the first click I want to change my .on() Method.

```
mySurface.on("touchstart",function(){
      doSomething();       
})
```

and after the first click I want to change it for example to:

```
mySurface.on("touchstart",function(){
      doSomethingDifferent();       
})
```

How can I overwrite my .on Method?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overwriting the `.on()` method is not really needed in your case here.

Here is one way to handle your use case.

```js
  var doSomethingElse = function(event) {
    console.log('doSomethingElse', event);
    console.log('mySurface', this);
  };

  var doSomething = function(event) {
    console.log('doSomething', event);
    console.log('mySurface', this);
    func = doSomethingElse;
  };

  var func = doSomething;

  mySurface.on("touchstart",function(event){
    func.call(this, event);       
  });
```